# MDI Panel not responsive

Tags: c#, winforms, anchor, responsive

on my windows forms start form I have two menu strips,a status bar and a panel.
I set the property *isMdi = true* for this panel. The anchor property is set to top, bottom, left and right.
Now I try to open a child form in the panel it doesn't resize if the parent form changes the size.

The code to open the child form:

```
                Form1 child = new Form1();
                child .TopLevel = false;
                child .AutoScroll = true;
                child .FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
                child .Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
                this.panelParent.Controls.Add(child );
                child .Show();
```

Why does the child not correctly resize? Do I need some other properties?
Any ideas?

Comment: What is the `isMdi` property? Isn't your Form a MDI Container (`IsMdiContainer = true`)? To add a child Form to a MDI **Form**, set `[ChildForm].MdiParent = this;` (where `this` is of course the current MDI Container Form).

Comment: If you're instead trying to set the Form as the *child* of a Panel control (the `MDI` model is unrelated) and you want the Panel to resize, set `[Panel].AutoSize = true;` and do not dock the Panel, anchor it.